# Show Custom Image in MapPin in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, maps

I have a map view in my view controller , in which i'm showing different locations in it. For that i have used my custom image to show those location, but  when the map loads it shows default pin image instead of mine custom image and when we tap on  map view twice or three time than it shows my custom image but not all of them few of them have my custom image and few contain default pin.How can i show my images when map loads. My code for adding custom image is this,

```
    -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    MKAnnotationView *view=[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annoView"];
    if (!view) {
        view=[[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annoView"];
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
            return nil;
        }else{
        view.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"car_marker.png"];
            view.canShowCallout=YES;
        }
    }


    return view;

}
```

Comment: check here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/1452094-image

Comment: You need to set the mapView's delegate BEFORE you add any of your annotations. Please double-check.

Comment: How to set it? @Mick

Comment: something like this "mapView.delegate = self" is already in your code. Otherwise you would never see your custom annotation view. I just assume that it happens AFTER map view started drawing. Once the map view has drawn its annotations, they won't redraw for quite a while. Just as you experienced.

Comment: Your method "viewForAnnotation" will only be executed after setting the map view's delegate.